# Run until no error occurred

Tags: r, function, try-catch

I want to execute a function which uses an internet connection to grep some online data. Because the connection is not very stable, it needs several attempts to run the function successfully. 
Therfore I want to repeat or loop the function until it worked and also save the results.

tryCatch seems to be a suitable function but so far I did not find a way to solve the problem. 
This is the function:

```
annotations(snp = 'rs1049434', output = 'snpedia')
```

and sometimes this error occur:

```
Error in annotations(snp = "rs1049434", output = "snpedia") : 
  server error: (502) Bad Gateway
```

The basic code schematically:

```
while( tmp == F){
  ifelse(result <- function worked, tmp <- T, tmp <- F)}
```

And I need the output `result` which is a data.frame.

ANSWER (see the link in the comment from nicola):

```
bo=0
while(bo!=10){
  x = try(annotations(snp = 'rs1049434', output = 'snpedia'),silent=TRUE)
  if (class(x)=="try-error") {
    cat("ERROR1: ", x, "\n")
    Sys.sleep(1)
    print("reconntecting...")
    bo <- bo+1
    print(bo)
  } else
  break 
}
```

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969070/assigning-a-value-in-exception-handling-in-r/28969896#28969896

Comment: How does that `tryCatch` code look like?